# Why IntelliJ IDEA is building the maven project when I only want to execute a kotlin script?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a maven project with a Kotlin script in it.
When I click run, instead of executing via the Kotlin compiler, it builds the Maven Project.
This takes 5 minutes. I want just the Kotlin compiler to compile and execute, which normally takes 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the way that the project was imported in IntelliJ IDEA.
I removed the .iml file and the .idea directory and imported the project again in IDEA.
This was enough and it works fine now.